# How to import only en impex during system update in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I did system update only with Create essential data checkbox selected. I noticed there are many impex get imported. For example essential-data.impex, essential-data_en.impex, essential-data_de.impex, essential-data_ch.impex ja, br etc. Nearly 7 different language specific impex are get imported. But I wanted to import only en version of it and other I don't want to import. Could you please suggest me how to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: One easy solution is, just to delete the other impex files. Or I mentioned below, delete the other languages from the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in the SystemSetup class.[hybris\bin\custom\training\src\com\training\setup\TrainingSystemSetup.java]

```
@SystemSetup(extension = MyExtension.EXTENSIONNAME, process = Process.UPDATE,type = Type.ESSENTIAL)
public class NaoCoreInitializer
{
    @SystemSetup(type = Type.ESSENTIAL)
    public static void setupEssential()
    {
        ImpexUtils.impex("essentialdata-en.impex");
        ImpexUtils.impex("essentialdata-de.impex");// you can add as many impex scripts you can
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Platform Update, it will always include all languages.

If you need to import 1 localized impex only, you can import via:

- HAC: Console > Impex Import
- Backoffice: System > Tools > Import

Comment: Can't we fix this in code? Every time when I do system update these files getting imported but my site supports only en so I don't want to include other language impex in system update process.

Comment: I think you can define the languages in your system. If you remove the other languages, the other impex files should not be imported.

Comment: @Mafick That is certainly possible. He can configure a SystemSetup that will remove the unnecessary languages during import for Essential Data (or wherever).